# Windows permission differences between spawning from Explorer and from cmd.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, cmd.exe, uac

I have noticed a strange behavior running a setup on Windows 10 that I can't understand. The setup creates a directory structure and, at a certain point, it renames one of the subdirectories it has created. What happened is explained below:

1. When I right-clicked the `setup.exe` in the Windows Explorer and selected "Run as administrator", the setup eventually failed because of a bad permission issue when trying to rename the subdirectory.
2. When I right-clicked on `cmd.exe`, run it as administrator and spawned the `setup.exe` from the command line, the setup completed successfully.

What was going on here? What's the difference between spawning an application from the Windows Explorer as administrator and spawning it from `cmd.exe` as administrator?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

- The root directory created by the setup is `c:\personal`. The initial subdirectory's path is: `c:\personal\platform\db`, and the renamed subdirectory should be: `c:\personal\platform\database`
- The user account running the setup belongs to the Administrators group and the setup process owner was this user in both cases.

Comment: *When I right-clicked  ..  the setup eventually failed ...*. It creates this subdirectory successfully, and immediately after this it cannot rename this created directory, is it?

Comment: @Akina, exactly, it's like this.

Comment: Show full pathname of this directory please. Is it posessed in Program files or similar?

Comment: @Akina, the root directory created by the setup is `c:\personal`. The initial subdirectory's path is: `c:\personal\platform\db`, and the renamed subdirectory should be: `c:\personal\platform\database`

Comment: Does your CURRENT account have administrative permissions (is a member of Administrators group)? Load ProcessExplorer, enable User Name column output, then start setup.exe both via right-click and via runas.exe, and compare account names shown.

Comment: @Akina, the current account is indeed a member of Administrators group. The setup (in both cases, running from Explorer and running from the command line) was being executed under the current account. This, actually, drove me nuts since everything was the same in terms of the user owning the process.

Comment: One difference is what the current active directory is in each case for the started process. If any of the paths is a relative path, then there could be a problem.

Comment: What are the permissions on the 'db' folder that cannot be renamed? Run `icacls db` from the personal folder and post the output in your question. Please ping me afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Administrator Accounts have a wide range of permissions in windows; However, they are still limited in what they can do. As an example, a Windows Admin Account lacks the permissions necessary to modify the files in the System 32 folder so long as they are owned by Trusted Installer. The admin does have permission to take ownership of the files, which THEN grants them the permission to modify the files, but cannot do so without having the ownership of the file.

On the other hand, when you launch an Administrator Command Prompt, the commands or services started from within that instance of cmd.exe are not run with Windows Administrator privileges. Instead, they are run with System privileges (note that the admin command prompt starts in the System 32 folder by default). System privileges are very similar to Admin privileges, with the main differences being that system permissions bypass some restrictions. In another thread it is stated:

> One practical difference is that, if the computer is joined to a domain, processes running as SYSTEM can access domain servers in the context of the computer's domain account. Processes running as Administrator have no access to domain computers unless the password happens to match or alternative credentials are explicitly provided.

It is important to note that System isn’t an account that you can log onto though, it is just a set of permission or an abstracted idea of the Operating System being a user.

Comment: Wrong. There is no way that any process elevated manually by user action or can run under the SYSTEM account. Please read the comment under my answer to understand that ALL user processes after elevation use the same process token and have identical permissions, no matter their starting condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about "Start in" parameter. Probably setup is using relative paths and when you start setup file by double clicking on it "Start in" parameter is the path of setup file. But if you run that setup file from cmd "Start in" parameter is different than the path of setup file.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I analyze the case you describe.

Windows Explorer is strangely programmed, in the sense that there is always only
one `explorer.exe` instance, even if several Explorer windows are opened,
and it is started during logon as a standard user, even if the login account
is that of an administrator.
This means that Explorer never runs in elevated mode, and that any process
started via Explorer inherits this running mode. If the started process wants
to acquire administrator permissions, it must demand elevation, thus requiring
user approval (if UAC is enabled).

On the other hand, if a process is started from an elevated `cmd.exe`,
it inherits this running mode, so it does not need to request elevation
(and if it does then this is immediately "granted" with no UAC prompt).

Now, I have started in the past installation programs from Explorer so many 
times, and they always requested elevation and worked without fault.
To be sure of the facts, I started an elevated `cmd.exe` as Admin both
from the command-line and from Explorer and compared their permissions using
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).
All permissions for both cases were absolutely identical.

This means that if the installation program you used was correctly programmed,
it would have had no problem. The inescapable conclusion is that it was
badly and weirdly programmed.
The fact that it found it necessary to rename its own folder, is already
an indication of something really strange.
My guess would be that it was created by one programmer, then was added-to
by another programmer that didn't dare modify the original code and only
appended more stuff to it.

I have tried to imagine what kind of error could cause such a problem,
and I only found the following, which you can verify by watching
the installation as it's working, using Process Explorer as the tool.

- The installation is not one process, meaning that the initial setup
  launched more than one process. Perhaps not all these processes requested
  elevation.
- That folder was deliberately created with permissions that precluded
  a non-administrator from modifying it, and the rename was attempted by
  an invoked rename process that wasn't elevated
  (it would have been elevated if it were launched from an already elevated process).
  You may verify this by right-click of the folder in Explorer,
  choosing Properties, and examining the Security tab.
- The rename was attempted by one non-elevated process while the folder was
  still opened by another elevated process, so couldn't be renamed.

These are not the only possibilities - there is an unlimited number
of possible programming errors.
The problem can only be fully understood by carefully
observing the installation while it is working.

Comment: The downvotes are based on lack of knowledge of how Windows accounts work and elevation in particular. I suggest reading the article [Understanding User Account Control (UAC), A Brief Summary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlupdates/2015/05/20/understanding-user-account-control-uac-a-brief-summary/) and especially the section of "Standard and Administrator Access Tokens".